# iSeries Navigator to access DB2 data on our IBM i

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange, navigator

We use iSeries Navigator to access DB2 data on our IBM i.
We have a problem with response times and the number of records extracted.
We have 35 million records on a file, and SQL via the iSeries Navigator only extracts 1 million, with a much longer response time.
We ran the same SQL directly on the IBM i, Green Screen (5250), and obtained the 35 million in 1 second.
Can anyone tell me what parameters to change in the iSeries Navigator to ignore this limitation of records?
Thank you very much for your help.

Best Regards,

Jean

We ran the same SQL directly on the IBM i, Green Screen (5250), and obtained the 35 million in 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

There is a 1 million record limit to the iSeries navigator.
This is not explicitly documented, but it is an obvious limitation.

I suggest using 3rd party tools like DBeaver.